# What is the Symbolic definition of a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From what i understand, a function from set A to B: $F: A\to B$, exists iff for every element a∈A there exists exactly one element b∈A such that $f(a) = b$.

Can this be expressed symboblically like this:

$$\forall a\in A: \exists !b\in B: f(a)=b$$

The defition of a function that im working with, is the one given in my Discrete Math book:

> "Let A and B be nonempty sets. A function f from A to B is an
>   assignment of exactly one element of B to each element of A. We write
>   f (a) = b if b is the unique element of B assigned by the function f
>   to the element a of A. If f is a function from A to B, we write f : A
>   → B.

Answer (score 0):

The standard symbol for "There exists a unique" is $\exists !$ . $\exists$ leaves open the possibility for more than one such element, which is not what you want. So you should write
$$\forall \ a \in A \ : \ \exists !\ b\in B \ : \ f(a)=b$$

Comment: Sort of. If it's not clear that $f$ is a single-valued relation then the notation $f(a) = b$ itself is not well-defined. That is, uniqueness seems to be presupposed, OP made no mention of a function as a relation (set of ordered pairs).

Comment: I interpret the OP as having a syntax error. When he/she writes $f(a)=b$, what is really meant is $b\in f(\{a\})$, and the question is really about when a relation is a function. Otherwise, by your own words, the first sentence has no content.

Comment: $(\forall a \in A)(\exists! b \in B) b \in f[\{a\}] $ -- I like that, yep.

Comment: I originally wrote ∃!, but someone edited my post and removed the exclamation point. Does the colon mean "such as", and is it illegal to write it like this: ∀x∃!b(a∈A b∈B) → (f(a) = b),when f(a) means the value in the codomain that is assigned a value from a∈A(image of a).

Comment: The definition im basing this quantified proposition of, is the definition of a function given in my Discrete Math book: "Let A and B be nonempty sets. A function f from A to B is an assignment of exactly one
element of B to each element of A. We write f (a) = b if b is the unique element of B
assigned by the function f to the element a of A. If f is a function from A to B, we write
f : A → B."

Answer (score 0):

Function are a special case of *relations*.

A relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A \times B$ – it's a set of ordered pairs $(a, b)$ where $a \in A, b \in B$. For any relation $R$, it's domain $dom(R)$ is all $a \in A$ for which there's some $b \in B$ with $(x, y) \in R$. If $X \subseteq A$, the image of $X$ under $R$ is $R[X] = \{b \in B \mid (a, b) \in R\}$.

A relation $F \subseteq A \times B$ is a *function* (on its domain) *iff* for every $a \in dom(F)$ there's a unique $b \in F[\{a\}]$ – in that case, we write $F(a) = b$.

$F$ is a *total* function on $A$ *iff* $dom(F) = A$ (otherwise it's "partial"), and in *that* case, we write $F\colon A \to B$.